# How do I convert this curl command to Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, json, curl, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I want to get data from my backend. I should set a request header with Authorization and use the generate auth_token from my previous interaction to the backend. 
here it is my curl

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Token token="replace-with-token"' http://domain.com/books
```

here it is my code

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.com/books"];
    config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    [config setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{@"token":@"4959a0bc00a15e335fb6"}];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]);
    }] resume];
```

I am not sure if I implemented the curl correctly. The data,which I received from backend, is null . Does any one know the reason?

Comment: here it is the right answer:
*http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344118/how-to-set-the-authorization-token-based-on-this-curl*

Answer (score 1):

A curl header of 'Authorization: Token token="replace-with-token"' would translate into:

```
[config setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{@"Authorization":@"token=\"4959a0bc00a15e335fb6\""}];
```