# how to set the authorization token based on this curl?

Tags: curl, header, token, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession

I want add a token for Authorisation to the header. Here it is the curl that my backend ask me to set before any interaction:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Token token="replace-with-token"' http://domain.com/topic
```

here is my code:

```
 [config setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{@"Authorization":@"token=\"4959a0bc00a15e335fb6\""}];
```

I keep getting "HTTP Token: Access denied." does any one know reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it would be this?:

```
[config setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{@"Authorization":@"Token token=\"4959a0bc00a15e335fb6\""}];
```